# Performance profiling Windows Phone 7 apps (SL/XNA)

Tags: silverlight, performance, profiling, xna, windows-phone-7

Is there performance profiler for Windows Phone 7 (SL/XNA)? I just want to measure execution time of calling methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the Mango update Microsoft has released its own profiling tool for Windows Phone as a part of the Windows Phone SDK (SDK version 7.1).

Here is a an article on [how to use the profiling tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934(v=vs.105).aspx). The advantage over using EQATEC is that you get this out of the box when you install the SDK. I used EQATEC quite some time ago for only a short period of time so can't objectively compare the feature set but for me the built-in profiler does the job and is exactly what I was long waiting for.

You can check if you have the profiler installed by checking if you have *Start Windows Phone Performance Analysis* (not *Start Performance Analysis*) in your *Debug* menu.

Also note that you must target the new version in the project settings (it appears as Windows Phone 7.1) in order to use the profiler.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum fixed that, just for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure the time it takes. You can also take a look at [frame rate counters](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/). A [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en) is also available, but I'm not sure how well that integrates into the emulator directly. However, you could create Windows applications and test your methods there. That CLR Profiler is targetted towards .NET 2, so you will have to add an Environment Variable to allow it to work with .NET 4. (To see how to add Environment Variables, [read this](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)). The details to enter are from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/79228e9d-d0de-473f-b044-e2bec69515a6):

> ```
> Name: COMPLUS_ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting
>
> Value: EnableV2Profiler
>
> Your Win32 XNA app will be a 32-bit application, so make sure you
> ```
>
> run the x86 version of CLRProfiler.

Answer (score 3):

There is now: [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler) 3.5 works for Windows Phone 7 Silverlight apps. It can profile your app on both the real phone-device as well as on the emulator (see eg [demo video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Worlds-first-profiler-for-Windows-Phone-7)). It's fully functional and free for single-assembly WP7 apps.

*Edit*: EQATEC Profiler 3.5.47 can profile **WP7 XNA apps**, too.